# Undo a git pull to be in sync with recovered remote master

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I pushed something from my local branch to remote master. This was a mistake and the admin will remove that push in the remote repo. In the mean time (by yet another mistake) I also pulled this change from remote master to local master. Now I want to obliterate this pull from my local repo, so that once remote repo goes to a previous state my repo will still be in sync with it.

Is it enough to right-click on previous revision in log dialog and select "reset 'master' to this..." (which does a `git reset` to a previous revision), and then revert all changes in working directory, or do I have to something else or something more?

Additional question. Is hard reset the same аs mixed reset followed up by a revert?

Comment: Resetting (hard) the master branch should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. To make sure everything is in sync, however, I would wait for the admin to remove your push, do a `git fetch` so that you have the latest `origin/master`, and then do a `git reset hard origin/master` while on your `master` branch. This will point your local `master` branch to the same commit `origin/master` points to. Note that if there are other developers who have pulled master since your accidental push, they will need to do the same.

As to your additional question: a `revert` creates a new commit, whereas a `reset` moves the current branch to point to a new commit, so a hard reset is not equivalent to a mixed reset plus a revert. It *is* equivalent to a mixed reset plus discarding changes in the working directory (e.g. by doing a `git checkout .`). Perhaps that is what you meant by "revert," but just want to be clear that an actual `git revert` is a different concept.